# Is there a way to write an object inside an existing HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html

How can I write an object inside this this div element

```
<div id="carsDivId">
 <p>The carsDiv</p>
</div>
```

I created an object like this inside my scripts?

```
var car = {
            "make" : carMake,
            "model" : carModel,
            "color" : carColor,
        };
```

I then to the following;

```
        var parent = document.querySelector('#carsDivId'); //fetch existing div element
        var pElement = document.createElement('p'); // create paragraph element
        var pElementId = document.createAttribute("id"); //create paragraph element id  
        pElementId.value = "par1"; //create the value of the id 
        pElement.setAttributeNode(pElementId); //assign the attribute to to an element
```

Write contents of my object inside variable txt

```
var txt = "";
        for(var x in car){
        txt += car[x] + " ";
        };
```

and do the follwing;

```
var pElementText = document.createTextNode(txt);
    pElement.appendChild(pElementText);
    parent.appendChild(pElement);
```

What is is that I'm doing wrong here because the content appears briefly an disappers in milliseconds?

Comment: I have the code at Pastbin https://pastebin.com/SSFS4feU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, where you're adding click handler through JQuery, but you're not preventing browsers default behaviour.

Solution: add `e.preventDefault` like this

```
$("#btn-enter").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: let me quickly test it. I'll comeback to you.

Comment: I have just tested it. It is working but I need to do more work in understanding jquery I must say. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> What is is that I'm doing wrong here because the content appears briefly an disappers in milliseconds?

While you haven't provided a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this is a pointing very firmly to you  running your JavaScript in response to something that causes the browser to navigate.

For example:

1. You click on a submit button with a click event listener
2. The click event makes the JavaScript update the DOM of the current page
3. The browser displays the modified page
4. The form submits to the URL specified in the `action` (which is the current URL if there isn't an `action`)
5. The browser loads the new page (which is the same as the old page before the JS ran).

Either:

- Make sure that submitting the form has the same effect as running the JS **and** [prevent the default behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) (see [Progressive Enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)) **or**
- Don't use a submit button (a `<button type="button">` is often a good choice).

(And the same applies if you are using a link rather than a submit button)

Comment: Thanks but then is it going to make a difference if I use: <input type="button" id="myBtn">? I must say I new with html and javascripting.

Comment: @Mgambu — If you don't use a submit button then you won't submit the form so you won't cause the page to reload. (If my assumptions are right; you didn't provide a mcve)